# Start Apache James with jdk 1.7

Tags: java, james

I have tried to run the apache-james-3.0-beta4 server on Linux Mint 64bit (Debian) with Java jdk 1.7u17, but it didn't work  due to the JAXB library bug. According to the documentation different jar file should be downloaded (http://jaxb.java.net/2.1.13/JAXB2_20100510.jar) and put into the conf/lib directory. I did that, but the problem is still there. When I switched to jdk 1.6, everything started to work fine.

Have anybody solved this problem?

Here is a part of the stack trace:

```
INFO  19:45:24,669 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@11641923: startup date [Mon Apr 22 19:45:24 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "outputs"
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at public java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition.getOutputs()
                at org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition.outputs
                at org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition

 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "outputs"
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at public java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition.getOutputs()
                at org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition.outputs
                at org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition
]
...
```

Comment: I haven't experienced this problem with James (but I have form a JBoss perspective), and to fix it you had to explicitly state the JAR file in your classpath before any wildcards.  Maybe that will help

Comment: It seems that next beta5 version would be fixed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JAMES-1450

Comment: No, beta5-854 doesn't work either. Different stack trace though.

Comment: maybe it's related to this one: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JAMES-1451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file I have downloaded was not the newest. When I have downloaded [newer version of beta5](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/james/james-server-app/3.0.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT/) it worked fine.

Comment: Link is broken.. you can find the beta5 here https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/james/apache-james/3.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Ya, every direct link would brake from time2time, when new revisions is available. They are keeping available only last 2 revisions. You can see which revision is currently available there and pick which you like.