# Apache James 3.0-beta4 start issue

Tags: java, apache, james

I thought of using Apache James 3.0-beta4 for mail server purpose. I downloaded it from apache website. Followed the instructions to run it. i ran "run.bat" but got the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStore
Exception: Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.
JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be
 instantiated: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException:
 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "outputs"
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at public java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefini
tion.getOutputs()
                at org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefin
ition.outputs
                at org.apache.camel.model.ResequenceDefinition
```

Looked everywhere but didn't find any solution. its the latest file that apache have as of now.
Please guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this issue. This problem happens when running java 7, revert back to java 6 as a work around.  It worked for me.

lee

Answer (score 1):

You need to the library below. Add to Resources.

- jaxb-api.jar
- jaxb-impl.jar

Answer (score 0):

Apache James 3.0-beta4 does not start on java 7, but starts on java 6.
Here is the answer: [Start Apache James with jdk 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154201/start-apache-james-with-jdk-1-7)

UPADTE: I was wrong. Actually, You can start beta4 on java 7. I just did it. You have to download the sources, edit the pom to use the camel-core-2.10.3 and build the project using maven.